# Why can't gradient systems have closed orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

I've seen the proof provided in Strogatz where he compares the change in the gradient function $V$ after one period $T$; on one hand, $\Delta V=0$ because $V(x(T)=V(x(0))$, while on the other, $\int dV=\int (\nabla V \bullet \dot x)dt=\int- ||x||^2dt$ which is always negative for any $x$ that moves at all. (I realize I am missing the limits $0, T$ in the integrals.)

While this proof is very neat, I'm still not really understanding why this all works out. Is there a way to understand this by a visual or a physical example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic example of a gradient system is water running down a hill.  The height of the hill is the potential, and the water runs in the direction of steepest descent. Having a closed orbit would imply that water could run downhill to itself, like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_%28M._C._Escher%29) Escher picture. Every gradient system can be thought of as something running "downhill".

Comment: Does that mean that whenever I see a strictly non-conservative system, it is a gradient system?

Comment: Gradient systems are exactly the conservative systems; conservative means that energy change in a closed loop is 0. The key thing is that closed loops just don't happen naturally in gradient systems. So if I carried the water in a bucket back to the top of the hill, the energy would go back to its original amount, but only because I forced it to.